# Specifying username/password in StreamReader

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to auto stream a text file to a `TextBox` with the **user** and **pass** being specified in the `StreamReader`.

This is my code:

```
Dim address As String = "http://www.domaintest.com/test/file.txt"
Dim webclient As NetworkCredential = "user:pass"
Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(client.OpenRead(address))
TextBox1.Text = reader.ReadToEnd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original example actually returned the file without specifying credentials. But if you want to specify credentials, you can do this

```
Dim address As String = "http://www.domaintest.com/test/file.txt"
Dim credentials As New NetworkCredential("user", "pass")
Using client As New WebClient()
    client.Credentials = credentials
    Using reader As New StreamReader(client.OpenRead(address))
        TextBox1.Text = reader.ReadToEnd
    End Using
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim postUrl As String = "Your URL"
Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(postUrl)
request.UseDefaultCredentials = False
request.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy
Dim nc As new NetworkCredential("UserName", "Password")
request.Proxy.Credentials = nc
request.Timeout = 10000
request.Method = "POST"
Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
Dim strmResp As System.IO.Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
Dim strmReader As System.IO.StreamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(strmResp,           System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")) 
Dim resp As String = strmReader.ReadToEnd()
strmReader.Close()
```

Comment: have problem `(HttpWebResponse)request` [screenshot](http://s8.picofile.com/file/8275777550/2016_11_23_124319.jpg)

Comment: Replace This Line: